# Error by wrapping c++ class with pybind11 using carma (armadillo matrices and numpy arrays)

Tags: python, c++, numpy, armadillo, pybind11

I have a simple example of trying to use [carma](https://carma.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html) and [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to go to and from armadillo matrices and numpy arrays based off of this [example](https://github.com/RUrlus/carma/blob/master/examples/example.cpp). Without the printarma() function, the code works i.e. with just wrapping using pybind11 the code compiles and I can run it in python. The problem here seems to be with carma. Here is the code:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <carma/carma.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void test() = 0;
    virtual void printarma() = 0;
};
class Derived: public Base
{

public:
    void printarma(py::array_t<double> & arr) {arma::Mat<double> mat = carma::arr_to_mat<double>(arr);
            std::cout << mat<< std::endl;}
    void test() {cout << "Test";}
};


PYBIND11_MODULE(example,m) {
    py::class_<Base>(m, "Base");

    py::class_<Derived, Base>(m, "Derived")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("test", &Derived::test);
        m.def("printarma", &Derived::printarma,py::arg("arr"));
}
```

I run the command:

```
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++14 -fPIC -larmadillo `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` abstrakt_test.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix`
```

And the errors are:

```
In file included from /home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:47,
                 from /home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/numpy.h:12,
                 from /usr/local/include/carma/carma/converters.h:24,
                 from /usr/local/include/carma/carma/arraystore.h:1,
                 from /usr/local/include/carma/carma.h:1,
                 from abstrakt_test.cpp:18:
/home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/init.h: In instantiation of ‘Class* pybind11::detail::initimpl::construct_or_initialize(Args&& ...) [with Class = Derived; Args = {}; typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_constructible<_Tp, _Args>::value), int>::type <anonymous> = 0]’:
/home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/init.h:174:66:   required from ‘static void pybind11::detail::initimpl::constructor<Args>::execute(Class&, const Extra& ...) [with Class = pybind11::class_<Derived, Base>; Extra = {}; typename std::enable_if<(! Class::has_alias), int>::type <anonymous> = 0; Args = {}]’
/home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:1148:9:   required from ‘pybind11::class_<type_, options>& pybind11::class_<type_, options>::def(const pybind11::detail::initimpl::constructor<Args ...>&, const Extra& ...) [with Args = {}; Extra = {}; type_ = Derived; options = {Base}]’
abstrakt_test.cpp:45:26:   required from here
/home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/init.h:63:64: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘Derived’
 inline Class *construct_or_initialize(Args &&...args) { return new Class{std::forward<Args>(args)...}; }
                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
abstrakt_test.cpp:31:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Derived’:
 class Derived: public Base
       ^~~~~~~
abstrakt_test.cpp:29:18: note:  ‘virtual void Base::printarma()’
     virtual void printarma() = 0;
                  ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/numpy.h:12,
                 from /usr/local/include/carma/carma/converters.h:24,
                 from /usr/local/include/carma/carma/arraystore.h:1,
                 from /usr/local/include/carma/carma.h:1,
                 from abstrakt_test.cpp:18:
/home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h: In instantiation of ‘void pybind11::cpp_function::initialize(Func&&, Return (*)(Args ...), const Extra& ...) [with Func = pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function(Return (Class::*)(Arg ...), const Extra& ...) [with Return = void; Class = Derived; Arg = {pybind11::array_t<double, 16>&}; Extra = {pybind11::name, pybind11::scope, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg}]::<lambda(Derived*, pybind11::array_t<double>&)>; Return = void; Args = {Derived*, pybind11::array_t<double, 16>&}; Extra = {pybind11::name, pybind11::scope, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg}]’:
/home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:78:9:   required from ‘pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function(Return (Class::*)(Arg ...), const Extra& ...) [with Return = void; Class = Derived; Arg = {pybind11::array_t<double, 16>&}; Extra = {pybind11::name, pybind11::scope, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg}]’
/home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:819:22:   required from ‘pybind11::module& pybind11::module::def(const char*, Func&&, const Extra& ...) [with Func = void (Derived::*)(pybind11::array_t<double>&); Extra = {pybind11::arg}]’
abstrakt_test.cpp:47:55:   required from here
/home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:133:50: error: static assertion failed: The number of argument annotations does not match the number of function arguments
         static_assert(expected_num_args<Extra...>(sizeof...(Args), cast_in::has_args, cast_in::has_kwargs),
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                 from /home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:44,
                 from /home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/numpy.h:12,
                 from /usr/local/include/carma/carma/converters.h:24,
                 from /usr/local/include/carma/carma/arraystore.h:1,
                 from /usr/local/include/carma/carma.h:1,
                 from abstrakt_test.cpp:18:
/home/mikanim/anaconda3/envs/pybind/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:1958:57: error: ‘std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<_Res>::value, pybind11::detail::void_type> pybind11::detail::argument_loader<Args>::call(Func&&) && [with Return = void; Guard = pybind11::detail::void_type; Func = pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function(Return (Class::*)(Arg ...), const Extra& ...) [with Return = void; Class = Derived; Arg = {pybind11::array_t<double, 16>&}; Extra = {pybind11::name, pybind11::scope, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg}]::<lambda(Derived*, pybind11::array_t<double>&)>&; Args = {Derived*, pybind11::array_t<double, 16>&}; std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<_Res>::value, pybind11::detail::void_type> = pybind11::detail::void_type]’, declared using local type ‘pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function(Return (Class::*)(Arg ...), const Extra& ...) [with Return = void; Class = Derived; Arg = {pybind11::array_t<double, 16>&}; Extra = {pybind11::name, pybind11::scope, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg}]::<lambda(Derived*, pybind11::array_t<double>&)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
     enable_if_t<std::is_void<Return>::value, void_type> call(Func &&f) && {
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Code without carma:

```
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` abstrakt_test.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix`



#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>


namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void test() = 0;
};
class Derived: public Base
{

public:

    void test() {cout << "Test";}
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(example,m) {
    py::class_<Base>(m, "Base");

    py::class_<Derived, Base>(m, "Derived")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("test", &Derived::test);
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this carma library, but I'm not sure the problem is related to it. It's been a long time since I have used pybind11, but if memory doesn't fail me you need a trampoline class whenever you have virtual classes (specially abstract classes). That is, you need to change `py::class_<Base>(m, "Base");` to something similar to `py::class_<Base, PyBase>(m, "Base");` and define the `PyBase` class in C++ using some pybind11 macros. Refer to [pybind11 documentation on this topic](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/classes.html#overriding-virtual-functions-in-python).

Comment: @darcamo thanks for the insight. If you were to remove everything with carma and armadillo from the code above, the code compiles and runs in python. So I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Pybind11 needs to be able to instantiate a C++ class for the binding and the compiler error clearly says that the problem is "... the following virtual functions are pure within ...". This is a strong indicator that you need the trampoline class. It will act as a concrete class that pybind can instantiate instead of the original abstract class. Also, you should declare the bind for the `test` method in `Base` and use `PYBIND11_OVERLOAD_PURE` in `Base`s trampoline class implementation.

Comment: Sounds much more confusing than I had before especially since everything with the virtual function already worked. I added code for the case without carma with the command and it works. I am not sure why just because I have a new function in the derived class that I have to update the test() function.

Comment: It is confusing indeed. But you **definitely need** a trampoline class here, even if this particular problem is not solved only by this. I can't try this code myself at the moment (and that is why I'm not writing a proper answer), but I still think that the problem is what I have described due to the error message you are getting.

Comment: I fixed the errors. The answer is below. Thanks nonetheless for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it was two things: the virtual function in the Base class needed to add `py::array_t<double> & arr` to it and the semicolon at the end at `.def` needed to be deleted along with the `m` before `.def`. This code compiles and works in python:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void test() = 0;
    virtual void printarma(py::array_t<double> & arr) = 0;
};
class Derived: public Base
{

public:
    void printarma(py::array_t<double> & arr) {arma::Mat<double> mat = carma::arr_to_mat<double>(arr);
            std::cout << mat<< std::endl;}
    void test()  {cout << "Test";}
};


PYBIND11_MODULE(example,m) {
    py::class_<Base>(m, "Base");

    py::class_<Derived, Base>(m, "Derived")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("test", &Derived::test)
        .def("printarma", &Derived::printarma,py::arg("arr"));
```

Comment: A yes, you were not really overriding `printarma` since the signatures were different. It is a good idea to always add `override` in methods in are overriding. If you add it to a method that is not really overriding anything such as in the case then you get an error.

Comment: @darcamo I'm curious -- what is the point of adding `override` when it already compiles and works? The error was mainly because inside the `printarma` function `py::array_t<double> & arr` was missing.

Comment: Sometimes you want to override a method from a base class, but you use a different signature by mistake. It will compile without problems, but instead of overriding you are overloading. Then you call the method with the original signature and the base class version is used (or you get a compile error if it is virtual pure as with `printarma`) instead of your new version. By adding [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) in your derived class version you get a compile time error early if that happens with a clear error message.

Comment: @darcamo thanks for the insight. So even if it compiles and works at the moment you thinks it is good practice to still use override?

Comment: Yes, and not only in this particular. Get the habit of always using override when you override a method.